# Windows Embedded CE DiskPrep PowerToy

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, bootable

I'm trying to find Windows Embedded CE DiskPrep PowerToy. 
Old link was on Microsoft archive gallery, but now it's retired.
Any hint for a new download link?
I need to create a bootable CF for Windows CE6 and Windows COmpact Embedded 7.
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea where it went.  Fortunately, I have it stored in our SCC server.  I've [published it here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2014/05/27/diskprep-availability/).

Comment: Does not work any more. Googling did not result any valid link :(